# Nested SideBar with or without Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, navigation, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to create Nested Left Sidebar with twitter bootstrap?
I checked their tutorials but couldn't find it.
I want to make a side bar with some listings and each listing contains nested lists which by default are hidden and when the user hover mouse on the list the hidden options should become visible.

```
<div class="span2">  
    <div class="well sidebar-nav">  
        <ul class="nav nav-list">  
            <li class="nav-header">Categories</li>  
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Books</a> 
                              <ul>
                                  <li><a href="#">Science Books</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Computer Books</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">History Books</a></li>
                               </ul>
                            </li>  
            <li><a href="#">Electronics</a></li> 
                                <ul>
                                  <li><a href="#">TV</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Freezer</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Radio</a></li>
                                </ul> 
            <li><a href="#">Computer</a></li>
        </ul>  
    </div> 
</div>
```

Is it possible to do it with twitter bootstarp ? If not any other solution ?

Thanks

Comment: [Collapse](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse)
You can mix collapse plugin with well+nav classes. [Little Exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/zzJ4w/)

Comment: @Oswaldo Acauan it works onclick and show the hidden content below. I need to change the js then?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zzJ4w/5/ PS. I dont know why this javascript in fiddle doesn't work, but in my develop environment works fine.

Comment: @Oswaldo Acauan its also not working with me :(

Comment: open this page http://fiddle.jshell.net/zzJ4w/5/show/ and try execute the javascript(without $(document).ready()) via firebug

Comment: @Oswaldo Acauan I didn't get what you want to say, but the jQuery function u wrote is inside style tag

Comment: uhauhauha just saw it now, sorry my mistake :P. Follow the correct fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zzJ4w/13/

Comment: I include ur latest js inside a script tag but its not working, actually the ul inside my li is not hidden by default but it is also not visible on the browser when the page loads

Comment: it woks on the link that you provided but not on my local system :(

Comment: you have jquery and twitter bootstrap javascript files?

Comment: yes I checked it I have 
<script src="/public/javascripts/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">
<script src="/public/javascripts/libs/bootstrap/collapse.js">

Comment: Thank you so munch for ur help actually i didn't include document.ready(function)... One last question can I style the list that is coming visible on hover and to move it right towards the parent li?

Comment: Yes, provided it is within the <li> father.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Collapse](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse) You can mix collapse plugin with well+nav classes. [Exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/zzJ4w/13)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this see the link given below

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </a>
            <a class="brand" href="#">Brand X</a>
            <div class="nav-collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Regular Link</a></li>                    
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Basic List <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Nested Lists<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="nav-header">Top Stuff</li>
                            <li class="nav nav-list">Nested List<b class="caret"></b>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>    
                                    <li><a href="#">Bat</a></li>                                
                                </ul>        
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav nav-list">Nested List<b class="caret"></b>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>    
                                </ul>    
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sit</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Amet</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="nav-header">Other Stuff</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bat</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.nav li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu li.nav-list:hover {
    background: #08c;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;    
}

.nav li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu .nav-list {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #333;
    float: none;
    line-height: 21px;
}

.nav li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.nav li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu ul {
    display: none;
    float:right;
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
    margin-top: -27px;
}

.nav li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu .nav-list .caret {
    border-bottom-color: #999;
    border-top-color: #999;
    float: right;
}

.nav li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu .nav-list:hover .caret {
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 1px;
    border-right: 0;
    border-left: 4px solid #fff;
    border-top: 4px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
}

.nav li.dropdown ul .nav-list .dropdown-menu:after {
    top: 8px;
    left: -12px;
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid #fff;
}

.nav li.dropdown ul .nav-list .dropdown-menu:before {
    left: -7px;
    border-left: 0;
    top: 7px;
    border-top: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/scottloway/S9yTU/